# Unable to create a user in FreeBsd: pw: user name or id required

Tags: freebsd

I'm trying to add a user:

```
$ sudo pw useradd -m -s /bin/tcsh -g grp1 user123
```

An error:

> pw: user name or id required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fine manual for `pw(8)` shows:

```
    pw [-R rootdir] [-V etcdir] useradd [-n] name [-u uid] ...
```

What happens when you copy the exact syntax indicated in the manual? E.g.

```
sudo pw useradd user123 -m -s /bin/tcsh -g grp1
```

or

```
sudo pw useradd -n user123 -m -s /bin/tcsh -g grp1
```